# Converting from String to &str with a different lifetime

Tags: string, rust, lifetime

I have this simple example:

```
fn make_string<'a>() -> &'a str {
    let s : &'static str = "test";
    s
}

fn make_str<'a>() -> &'a str {
    let s : String = String::from_str("test");
    s.as_slice()
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", make_string());
    println!("{}", make_str());
}
```

Error message:

```
<anon>:8:9: 8:10 error: `s` does not live long enough
<anon>:8         s.as_slice()
                 ^
<anon>:6:34: 9:6 note: reference must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the block at 6:33...
<anon>:6     fn make_str<'a>() -> &'a str {
<anon>:7         let s : String = String::from_str("test");
<anon>:8         s.as_slice()
<anon>:9     }
<anon>:6:34: 9:6 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block at 6:33
<anon>:6     fn make_str<'a>() -> &'a str {
<anon>:7         let s : String = String::from_str("test");
<anon>:8         s.as_slice()
<anon>:9     }
error: aborting due to previous error
playpen: application terminated with error code 101
Program ended.
```

It seems that the borrow checker recognizes that 'static is a greater lifetime than 'a so the conversion for make_string works, but make_str fails. Is there a way to create a reference from String and extend it to lifetime 'a, since String is heap allocated?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I return an &str value generated from a String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29781331/why-cant-i-return-an-str-value-generated-from-a-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a fundamental misconception here: `String` **is not heap allocated**.

The *content* of `String` is heap allocated, but its lifetime is tied to the lifetime of the `String` object itself, and whenever `String` is dropped (here, at the end of `make_str`), then the content of `String` is dropped too.

Therefore, the compiler is right: the lifetime of the result `String::as_slice` is less than or equal to that of `String` and the lifetime of `String` ends with the function... thus you cannot return a reference to it.

Comment: Related question, say I created a String within a method of an object and I wanted to both set the object's field and return the String. If I return the String it would transfer ownership, which is not allowed since the field has it too. Is there a way to do this without cloning the string?

Comment: @noisecapella: You should [post a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Remember that Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum. :)