# Why can't I return an &str value generated from a String?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm having some trouble trying to grasp why I can't return an `&str` value generated from a `String` (goodness, when will `as_str` be ready?) and I'm doing something wrong. I get this idea because nothing that I do makes the value live long enough to use.

I'm trying to implement `error::Error` for a custom struct:

```
impl error::Error for LexicalError {
    fn description(&self) -> &str {
        let s = format!("{}", self);

        // s doesn't live long enough to do this, I've tried 
        // cloning s and using that, but still the clone doesn't
        // live long enough.
        s.trim()
    }

    fn cause(&self) -> Option<&error::Error> {
        None
    }
}
```

(for the complete snippet, here is the [playpen](http://is.gd/i9OM9L))

I can't figure out how to return an &str from `description`, I'd like to reuse the `Display` logic, unless of course I'm completely misunderstanding what `description` should be returning (perhaps the short description of the issue). Either, I get the same issue with the return of `format!(...)` which is a variable I can't seem to get to live long enough to be useful to me.

Comment: `description` is supposed to be a description of the error not going into details; `fmt::Display` is supposed to be there to augment it with details as desired.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan I'm coming from Go as the most recent language I played with and I mistakenly assumed the description method was similar to Go's Error method. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First, let’s take a look at what lifetime is actually expected. There is an implicit lifetime in the signature of `description`:

```
fn description(&self) -> &str
// Can be rewritten as
fn description<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a str
```

The returned pointer must be valid for at least as long as `self`. Now consider `s`. It will hold a `String`, an owned string, and it goes out of scope at the end of the function. It would be invalid to return `&s`, because `s` is gone when the function returns. `trim` returns a string slice that borrows `s`, but the slice is again only valid for as long as `s` is.

You need to return a string slice that outlives the method call, so this rules out anything on the stack. If you were free to choose the return type, a solution would be to move the string out of the function. For that an owned string would be required, and then the return type would be `String`, not `&str`. Unfortunately, you are not free to choose the return type here.

To return a string slice that outlives the method call, I see two options:

1. Use a `&'static` string slice. This will certainly outlive the call, but it requires that the string is known at compile time or to leak memory. String literals have type `&'static str`. This is a suitable option if the description does not contain any dynamic data.
2. Store an owned string in `LexicalError` itself. This ensures that you can return a pointer to it that is valid for the entire lifetime of `self`. You can add a field `desc: String` to `LexicalError` and do the formatting when the error is constructed. Then the method would be implemented as

   ```
    fn description(&self) -> &str {
        &self.desc
    }
   ```

   For re-use, you can make `Display` write the same string.

According to the [documentation of `Error`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/index.html), `Display` may be used to provide additional detail. If you wish to include dynamic data in the error, then `Display` is a great place to format it, but you can omit it for `description`. This would allow the first approach to be used.

Comment: I think the second option will suit me best. Which leads me to ask a semi-related question - are `String` and `&str` interchangeable? Or, I suppose `String` and `str` in this case, other wise you'd be returning a borrowed `&str`. I have a poor understanding of the exact difference between `String` and `&str` other than when they occur (such as, I know the type of string literals and when building strings more complex than simple formatting I use `String`) and when to (slightly) choose between them.

Comment: They are not interchangeable. A `String` owns its UTF-8 bytes, whereas a `&str` merely points to UTF-8 bytes borrowed from somewhere. `String` and `&str` are analogous to `Vec<T>` and `&[T]`. You can borrow a `String` to obtain a `&str`. In that case, the borrowed slice cannot outlive the owning `String`. There is [a chapter about strings in the book](http://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0-beta.2/book/strings.html), which may be useful.

Comment: I've been through the book, what you said makes more sense than what I recall. Perhaps I just hadn't gotten enough of an understanding of the language to grasp that section. Thanks for info, it's been a great help.

Comment: In your example you show a few notations. What's the semantic difference between `&'a` and `&'static`? I get that `&'static` is a lifetime that lasts for the lifetime of the whole program, but I'm not sure what `&'a` means. What other `&'<something>` are available, if any?

Comment: The `'a` comes from the `<'a>` lifetime parameter. In addition to type parameters, methods in Rust can have lifetime parameters. So `fn description<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a str` means: for every lifetime `'a`, if you lend out `self` for `'a`, you get back a `&str` that is valid for `'a`.

Answer (score 0):

you can Box::leak() a static str from String, after use, drop it manually.

```
fn main() {
    let s1 = format!("abc");

    // s is static lifetime, can match the lifetime of &str
    let s = Box::leak(s1.into_boxed_str()); 

    // drop it manually.
    unsafe {
        mem::drop(Box::from_raw(s as *const str as *mut str));
    }
}
```

Comment: `drop` is in the prelude, no need to prefix it with `mem` or `use` it. [`String::leak`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.leak) is much more straight forward than first turning the string into a `Box<str>` also `&mut str` coerces to `*mut str` so your `as *… str` caists are redundant.

Comment: It's also not a good idea to leak memory on every function call.