# Borrow issue returning &format! in pattern

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying to return the result of a `format!` after pattern matching an `enum`:

```
enum Enm {
    Cont(String)
}

fn call(enm: &Enm) -> &str {
    match *enm {
        Enm::Cont(ref s) => &format!("{}", s)
    }
}

fn main() {

}
```

But this won't work: `borrowed value does not live long enough`

How can I solve this?

Comment: @Shepmaster I need this for `fn description(&self) -> &str` in the Error trait.

Comment: I understand, but that doesn't change the fact that you cannot do it (for all the reasons in the duplicate). Perhaps you'd also be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/q/29781331/155423.