# Proper way to return a new string in Rust

Tags: rust

I just spent a week reading the Rust Book, and now I'm working on my first program, which returns the filepath to the system wallpaper:

```
pub fn get_wallpaper() -> &str {
    let output = Command::new("gsettings");
    // irrelevant code
    if let Ok(message) = String::from_utf8(output.stdout) {
        return message;
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

I'm getting the error `expected lifetime parameter on &str` and I know Rust wants an input `&str` which will be returned as the output because any `&str` I create inside the function will be cleaned up immediately after the function ends.

I know I can sidestep the issue by returning a `String` instead of a `&str`, and many answers to similar questions have said as much. But I can also seemingly do this:

```
fn main() {
    println!("message: {}", hello_string(""));
}

fn hello_string(x: &str) -> &str {
    return "hello world";
}
```

to get a `&str` out of my function. Can someone explain to me why this is bad and why I should never do it? Or maybe it's not bad and okay in certain situations?

Comment: I don't really see how you can avoid this. You can try and make it cheaper, by preallocating buffers, but someone has to own this memory. You can't know the length of your string before reading it from the command's output. Allocating on the heap makes sense to me.

Comment: @bluejekyll i've clarified my question to show one way you seemingly can get a &str out of a function simply by providing a dummy parameter to have a lifetime.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You [cannot return a `&str` if you've allocated the `String` in the function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29428227/155423). There's further discussion about [why](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29781331/155423), as well as the fact that it's [not limited to strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32682876/155423). That makes your choice *much* easier: return the `String`.

> `String`s are heap-allocated and built to be mutable.

`String`s are heap-allocated because they have an unknown length. Since that allocation is solely owned by the `String`, that's what grants the ability to mutate the string.

> My function just returns a filepath for reference purposes, and I'd rather leave it up to the caller to decide if they need a heap-stored mutable string.

This isn't possible. Your function has performed an allocation. If you don't return the allocation to the caller, then the value must be deallocated to prevent memory leaks. If it was returned after deallocation, that would be an invalid reference, leading to memory safety violations.

> But I can also seemingly do this:
>
> ```
> fn hello_string(x: &str) -> &str {
>     return "hello world";
> }
> ```
>
> to get a `&str` out of my function. Can someone explain to me why this
>   is bad and why I should never do it? Or maybe it's not bad and okay in
>   certain situations?

It's not *bad*, it just doesn't really allow you to do what you want in your original case. That `"hello world"` is a `&'static str`, a string slice that's been stored inside the code of the program itself. It has a fixed length and is known to live longer than `main`.

The signature `fn hello_string(x: &str) -> &str` can be expanded to `fn hello_string<'a>(x: &'a str) -> &'a str`. This indicates that the resulting string slice must have the *same* lifetime as the input string. A static string will outlive *any* lifetime, so that's valid to substitute.

This would be useful for a function where the result is based on the input string only:

```
fn long_string(x: &str) -> &str {
    if x.len() > 10 {
        "too long"
    } else {
        x
    }
}
```

However, in your case, the function owns the `String`. If you attempted to return a reference to a `String`, completely unrelated to the input string:

```
fn hello_string(x: &str) -> &str {
    &String::from("hello world")
}
```

You'll run into the common error message "borrowed value does not live long enough". That's because the borrowed value only lives until the end of method, not as long as the input string slice. You can't "trick" the compiler (or if you can, that's a major bug).

Comment: Aren't references just like a (C/C++) pointer to a memory location? Isn't `String::from("hello world")` allocated in the heap? Why can't Rust just return a reference (pointer) to that heap location then? I'm really confused by this point.

Comment: @JohnTortugo yes, references *are* like a pointer in many ways (and not, in others). If you saw a C function like `char *foo()`, do you free the returned data or not? `String` is effectively a struct with `(allocated_capacity, used_size, pointer_to_heap_allocation)`.

Comment: Thanks, @Shepmaster. With `char *foo()` at least I have the option to [not] free if I need to keep the reference longer.

Comment: @JohnTortugo not really, because you don’t know *if* you can free it in the C code based on just the signature. Rust removes the ambiguity by splitting the two concepts into two types.

Comment: Great answer @Shepmaster. But you mentioned that:

> A static string will outlive any lifetime, so that's valid to substitute.

But if that's true, why must there be at least one parameter to compare a static var to? I.e., it's not clear to me why not `fn hello_string() -> &str {`

Thanks!

Comment: @Serg that function signature doesn't fit any of the [lifetime elision rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html#lifetime-elision), so the compiler doesn't know what lifetime to use.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to return a `&str` in Rust you have to add generic lifetime. Example:

```
fn hello_string<'life>() -> &'life str {
    return "hello world";
}
```

or,

```
fn hello_string<'life>(a: &'life str, b: &'life str) -> &'life str {
    return "hello world";
}
```

Here have a 3 rules.

1. Each parameter that is a reference gets it's own lifetime parameter.
2. If there is exactly one input lifetime parameter, that lifetime is assigned to all output lifetime parameters.
3. If there are multiple input lifetime parameters, but one of them is `&self` or `&mut self` the lifetime of self is assigned to all output lifetime parameters.