# How to return a &str, avoiding "temporary value dropped while borrowed"

Tags: rust

I'm having trouble unwrapping Options and converting the values to string slices.

- When the Option has `Some` value, I want to convert it to a `&str`.
- When the Option is `None`, I simply return an empty string slice `""`.

For example:

```
let val: Option<u8> = row.get(k);
match val {
    None => "",
    Some(v) => v.to_string().as_str()
}
```

But this fails with errors like this.

```
temporary value dropped while borrowed
consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value rustc E0716
main.rs(.....): temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
```

I have tried breaking it down in various different ways, for example like this

```
let val: Option<u8> = row.get(k);
match val {
    None => "",
    Some(v) => {
        let vstr = v.to_string();
        vstr.as_str()
    }
}
```

But I'm still really stuck.  I've looked through a many similar problems but none are quite the same, and I'm still stuck. How can I do this?

Clarification, I want the decimal representation of the tinyint, not the character point.  This is not utf8 string, just a number.

```
let x: u8 = 10;
let s: String = x.to_string();
println!("10 = {}", s);
```

This should print `10 = 10`

Comment: u8 is a single byte, shouldnt it be [u8] ?

Comment: Or, is it really `Option<u8>` and maybe you want to convert that 8 bit integer into it's decimal representation in a string?

Comment: @antoninGRAVIL, no not really meant to be a byte char.  think of it as a tinyint, harmic, yes more like a decimal representation in a string is what I want.

Comment: it's because you are borrowing from `vstr` which is dropped when it goes out of scope. Since you are returning a reference, that reference must point to something that outlives the reference. Try returning a `String` instead of an `&str`.

Comment: @Mel  YES!  by using String I'm able to work around it for now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proper way to return a new string in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43079077/proper-way-to-return-a-new-string-in-rust)

Comment: @Jmb, I'd say that link only indirectly helps, because it adds to my understanding of the underlying concepts, ie; lifetime and ownership.  I'm not returning a string. Thanks for sharing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to use the `&str` in the same function, you can hoist the declaration so that the string lives long enough:

```
let val: Option<u8> = row.get();
let vstr;
let msg = match val {
    None => "",
    Some(v) => {
        vstr = v.to_string();
        vstr.as_str()
    }
};
println!("value is {}", msg);
```

If your goal is to return the `&str` to a caller, then that's not possible.  That's a borrowed value, and the string that owns the memory won't live past the end of the function at most.  You can either return `String` or `Cow<'static, str>`.

For example, you could do this:

```
let val: Option<u8> = row.get();
match val {
    None => "".to_owned(),
    Some(v) => v.to_string(),
}
```

or this:

```
let val: Option<u8> = row.get();
match val {
    None => "".into(),
    Some(v) => v.to_string().into(),
}
```

Comment: The last snippet seems to be missing type ascription, e.g. `let msg: Cow<'static, str> = match val { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

In the more general case, when you cannot keep the string around, you could use [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html):

```
let val: Option<u8> = row.get(k);
let msg = match val {
    None => Cow::Borrowed(""),
    Some(v) => Cow::Owned(v.to_string()),
};
```

Now `msg` holds either a borrowed or an owned string, depending on the situation.