# Struct str attribute must be reference?

Tags: string, struct, rust

For the following code:

```rust
fn get_lines() -> String {
    String::from("Hello\nWorld")
}

fn get_first_line(s: &String) -> &str {
    s.lines().next().unwrap()
}

struct World<'a> {
    a_str: &'a str,
}

fn work<'a>() -> World<'a> {
    let s1 = get_lines();
    let s2 = get_first_line(&s1);

    World { a_str: s2 }
}

fn main() {
    let w = work();
}
```

I got the following error:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `s1`
  --> src/main.rs:17:5
   |
15 |     let s2 = get_first_line(&s1);
   |                             --- `s1` is borrowed here
16 | 
17 |     World { a_str: s2 }
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

How to build a struct instance using `s2`? Is it a conceptual error of the `World` struct?

Comment: "How to build a Struct instance using s2 ?" => `s2.to_string()`. "Is it a conception error of World struct ?" => why not put use a `String` in `World` ?

Comment: @Stargateur a String is a possibility yes. I am a beginner so i have no arguments ^^

Comment: Also see [Return local String as a slice (&str)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29428227/3650362), [Why can't I return an &str value generated from a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29781331/3650362), [Is there any way to return a reference to a variable created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32682876/3650362)... Honestly, if you just search [rust] for [cannot return value referencing local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brust%5D+cannot+return+value+referencing+local+variable) you will find a lot of related questions with answers.

Answer (score 1):

`World` refers to a `str` slice which must be owned by something else. Your function `work` allocates a new `String` (through `get_lines`), and makes a reference into it (through `get_first_line`). When it returns, the `String` goes out of scope and will be dropped, so you cannot keep a reference to it, since the thing it refers to is no longer there.

If you want a `World` object that does not depend on a `String` owned by something else, it will need to own the data itself: Contain a `String` instead of a `&'a str`.

See also ['dangling references' in the Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html#dangling-references).

Comment: Please refrain from answering [questions that are duplicates of existing questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55548553/struct-str-attribute-must-be-reference#comment97799445_55548553). Doing so spreads little bits of knowledge around to many places as opposed to consolidating them in a few well-maintained locations. It also makes it less likely for previous answers to get deserved upvotes and critical eyes. In the worst cases, it encourages question askers to not search for duplicates themselves.